# How to write Variable on file without add :new line: from "scanf" in C

Tags: c

always the first line of my file is empty

whst can i do ?

````
printf("donner n");
scanf("%d",&n);

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 { gets(ch);    
   fprintf(f,"%s\n",ch);} ```
````

Comment: Read the newline with `getchar()`?

Comment: Regarding with GETS(3) linux manual page tell us that `gets` is a deprecated function I recomment you that use getline, in any case if you need to jump the first emptly line use `get` or `getline` once before the `for`

Comment: You should tell us your expected result, and your efforts so far in debugging. People will be more likely to help if you give more information and context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

to

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

Should be able to get the results you want

Because the first empty line is a newline character that is not read at scanf.

Comment: I use... " fflush(stdin); "   // after scanf("%d",&n);  and It 'S WORKING
Thank you all for your Supports .